# How to develop pocketsphinx for android to get better quality with arabic recognition from 77 trys get only one word?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

the problem was there is no error messages and it didn't recognize any word!!
I use the model files from sphinx Arabic version which I tested before with eclipse on desktop and it works well but i don't know why it doesn't with pocketsphoinx and android.
 use feat.params and doesn't work and removed it and wide the range to "1e-40f" and after 77 try get only one corect!!
I use this code :

```
private void setupRecognizer() {
        File modelsDir = new File("/storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL");

        recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "model"))
                .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/an4.dic"))
                .setRawLogDir(new File(modelsDir, "logdir"))
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-1f)
                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);


        File digitsGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/grammar.gram");
        recognizer.addKeywordSearch(SEARCH_KEYWORD, digitsGrammar);
    }
```

to set up the recognizer and call `recognizer.startListening(SEARCH_KEYWORD);` when press & hold on button and `recognizer.stop();` when the hold is up.

## This is content of the grammar.gram

إِدْرَاجْ
 إِسْتِبدَالْ
 إِطَارْ
 إِغْلاقْ
 إِنْهَاءِ_الْعَرْض 
 الأَخِيرْ
 التَالِي
 السَابِقْ
 اللُغَةْ
 الْمَسْطَرَةْ
 بَحْث
 تَحْرير
 تَخْصِيص
 تَعْلِيمَاتْ
 تَكْبِيرْ
 تَنسِيق
 جَديد
 جَدْوَلْ
 حِفِظْ 
 خَصَائِص
 خَطّْ
 خَيَاراتْ
 صُورَة 
 طِباعَة
 عَرْضْ 
 فَتِحْ 
 قَصّْ
 لَصقْ
 مَلَفْ 
 مُسَاعَدَةْ
 نَسِخْ

## and this is the code for result :

```
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis arg0) {
    String comando=null;
    if(arg0!=null){
        if(arg0.getHypstr()!=null)
        {
            comando = arg0.getHypstr();
            Log.i("Result",comando);
            recognized_word.setText(comando);

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hup) {
    String comando=null;
    if(hup!=null){
        if(hup.getHypstr() !=null){
            comando = hup.getHypstr();
            Log.i("Result",comando);
            recognized_word.setText(comando);
        }
    }
}
```

## and this the updated log came from after replacing **1e-1f** by **1e-40f** and removing feat.params file one result came from 77 try!!

```
03-17 22:38:07.183 27950-27950/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-17 22:38:07.244 27950-27950/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.azizax.voicer, real application class is null.
03-17 22:38:07.249 27950-27956/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-17 22:38:08.025 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmd_ln.c(696): Parsing command line:
03-17 22:38:08.025 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: Current configuration:
03-17 22:38:08.062 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
03-17 22:38:08.063 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
03-17 22:38:08.063 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/mdef
03-17 22:38:08.167 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 7615 * 8 bytes (59 KiB) for CD tree
03-17 22:38:08.169 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/transition_matrices
03-17 22:38:08.172 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: acmod.c(123): Attempting to use SCHMM computation module
03-17 22:38:08.177 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/means
03-17 22:38:08.222 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1175 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
03-17 22:38:08.222 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  16x39
03-17 22:38:08.222 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/variances
03-17 22:38:08.255 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1175 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
03-17 22:38:08.255 27950-27950/? I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  16x39
03-17 22:38:08.379 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 209 variance values floored
03-17 22:38:08.380 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: acmod.c(125): Attempting to use PTHMM computation module
03-17 22:38:08.385 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/means
03-17 22:38:08.405 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1175 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
03-17 22:38:08.405 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  16x39
03-17 22:38:08.405 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/variances
03-17 22:38:08.422 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1175 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
03-17 22:38:08.422 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  16x39
03-17 22:38:08.544 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 209 variance values floored
03-17 22:38:08.544 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ptm_mgau.c(792): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 1175
03-17 22:38:08.545 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: acmod.c(127): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation
03-17 22:38:08.545 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/means
03-17 22:38:08.567 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1175 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
03-17 22:38:08.567 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  16x39
03-17 22:38:08.567 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/variances
03-17 22:38:08.584 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 1175 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
03-17 22:38:08.584 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  16x39
03-17 22:38:08.714 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 209 variance values floored
03-17 22:38:08.720 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/model/mixture_weights
03-17 22:38:08.722 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits
03-17 22:38:08.722 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory
03-17 22:38:08.728 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 1175 senones: 1 features x 16 codewords
03-17 22:38:08.728 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks
03-17 22:38:08.728 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: ms_mgau.c(141): The value of topn: 4
03-17 22:38:08.732 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 4129 * 20 bytes (80 KiB) for word entries
03-17 22:38:08.732 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/dict/an4.dic
03-17 22:38:08.733 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
03-17 22:38:08.733 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict.c(336): 33 words read
03-17 22:38:08.733 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
03-17 22:38:08.733 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 35^3 * 2 bytes (83 KiB) for word-initial triphones
03-17 22:38:08.735 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 14840 bytes (14 KiB) for word-final triphones
03-17 22:38:08.735 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 14840 bytes (14 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
03-17 22:38:08.735 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: kws_search.c(420): KWS(beam: -1080, plp: -23, default threshold -900)
03-17 22:38:08.761 27950-28148/com.example.azizax.voicer D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-17 22:38:08.827 27950-28148/com.example.azizax.voicer I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
03-17 22:38:08.833 27950-28148/com.example.azizax.voicer I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-17 22:38:17.162 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:38:17.162 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:38:17.189 27950-28460/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000000.raw
03-17 22:38:17.498 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/onBeginningOfSpeech: Hello
03-17 22:38:17.721 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:38:50.122 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:38:50.122 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:38:50.126 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/Result:  لَصقْ     نَسِخْ    
03-17 22:38:50.141 27950-29106/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000022.raw
03-17 22:38:50.324 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:39:41.032 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:39:41.032 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:39:41.040 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000033.raw
03-17 22:39:41.280 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/onBeginningOfSpeech: Hello
03-17 22:39:41.763 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:39:41.864 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.57 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.32 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.05 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.07 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.37 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.03 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.17 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.25 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.19 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.09 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.74 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.23 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.13 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.37 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.16 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:41.865 27950-30040/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:41.883 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Stop recognition
03-17 22:39:41.884 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:39:41.884 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:39:41.888 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000034.raw
03-17 22:39:42.223 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.74 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.23 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.37 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.16 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.74 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.23 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.37 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.16 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:42.295 27950-30055/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:42.296 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Stop recognition
03-17 22:39:42.297 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:39:42.297 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:39:42.306 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000035.raw
03-17 22:39:42.744 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:39:42.877 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 
03-17 22:39:42.877 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.74 
03-17 22:39:42.877 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.23 
03-17 22:39:42.877 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:42.877 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.877 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.37 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.16 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.58 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.12 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.36 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.21 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:42.878 27950-30062/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:42.896 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Stop recognition
03-17 22:39:42.896 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:39:42.896 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:39:42.897 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:39:42.902 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000036.raw
03-17 22:39:42.920 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.58 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.12 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.36 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.21 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.58 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.12 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.36 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.21 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:39:42.921 27950-30075/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:39:42.932 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Stop recognition
03-17 22:40:21.789 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:40:21.789 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "x"
03-17 22:40:21.802 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(901): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/VoiceR/MODEL/logdir/000000037.raw
03-17 22:40:21.863 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=889.0, y[0]=716.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=49287375, downTime=49287308, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
03-17 22:40:21.881 27950-28148/com.example.azizax.voicer D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1f77600 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9fcfe720
03-17 22:40:21.884 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=889.0, y[0]=715.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=49287383, downTime=49287308, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
03-17 22:40:21.885 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=889.0, y[0]=715.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=49287393, downTime=49287308, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
03-17 22:40:21.885 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=889.0, y[0]=715.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=49287393, downTime=49287308, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
03-17 22:40:21.885 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=889.0, y[0]=715.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=49287393, downTime=49287308, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
03-17 22:40:25.106 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: start Recording
03-17 22:40:25.524 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/startbtn: stop Recording
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: 11.58 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.06 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.12 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.36 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:40:25.618 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.15 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.28 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.08 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.21 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  9.95 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.16 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.01 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx:  0.07 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.30 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.04 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.12 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.13 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.10 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.22 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.07 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.16 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: -0.09 
03-17 22:40:25.619 27950-30659/com.example.azizax.voicer I/cmusphinx: >
03-17 22:40:25.634 27950-27950/com.example.azizax.voicer I/SpeechRecognizer: Stop recognition
```

you can find the whole activity code and the updated model(included the feat.params files) folder from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iyvxa0a1sTRUVScHlMeVk4NlE)

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev that's the problem (I don't know where is the problem?) if you see the log maybe help!!

Comment: can u point me to link or something to build model,dict,grammar to be able to use pocketsphinx on android correctly , i followed this link : http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial but doesn't work! @NikolayShmyrev

Comment: The log is ok, the tutorial is on website, if you follow it properly it should work. As far as I see you application works as expected.

Comment: what is the meaning of "the log is ok" , Didn't recognize any word !! @NikolayShmyrev

Comment: ok, so the problem is that it doesn't recognize any word. It is great you finally figured that out. Now update the question to point clearly what the problem is. And include code as text instead of pictures.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Updated , Can you look please.

Comment: Looks better, but you forgot to update the question title to reflect the problem

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev updated and added the file but got error plz help!

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev updated

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Format updated.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev only one be recognized from 77 times !! short log provided inside the question which be updated and the entire log [accuracylog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iyvxa0a1sTZ2trTVM4aFM0aG8)
can you please help me figuring out how to improve it?

Comment: Can you please provide a link for newer more accurate Arabic model?
@NikolayShmyrev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wider threshold, 1e-40 instead of 1e-1, threshold tuning is covered in [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm)

Comment: tried "1e-40" and updated the question title and question itself ..  there is error when i added the feat.params i added the feat.params i used to drive i mentioned the link in the question and i added the log of the error message too.

Comment: no it doesn't ! 
note i cleared the cache and rebuilt and everything ok but still not recognize any word.

Comment: Please format it properly as a code, not as a quote.

Comment: Ok, please provide log with several attempts, not just a single attempt. And try to speak for a longer time.

Comment: i tried 77 times and got only one result , the limit of stackoverflow make me provide short log , the whole log you can find inside the link of the drive "accuracylog" why only one be recognized out of 77 !!

Comment: Ok, congratulations, so it recognizes. Now you need more accurate model, newer pocketsphinx and proper threshold tuning as described in tutorial

Comment: Thanks :D
Can you please provide a link for newer more accurate Arabic model?